# Drupal Home Page

Tags: drupal

Any way to make my CiviCRM Drupal site go to the module when I hit the homepage?  Right now I have to type ?q=civicrm/dashboard after my root.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh.. found it /#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin%252Fconfig%252Fsystem%252Fsite-information

(Drupal) configuration -> site information -> front page

Comment: You have found your answer but you might also want to look at enabling 'clean urls' in Drupal to get rid of the ?q= stuff - https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls

Comment: And are you able to Accept your own answer

Comment: I think it takes 48 hours from posting because I can in 7h.  Thanks